# Omitir registros repetidos

Tags: laravel

como puedo omitir registros repetidos?
Hago esta consulta:

```
Reservas::where('user_id', $user)->where('dia_id', $dia)->get();
```

Esto me devuelve varios registros de un usuario, lo que necesito es que en la tabla del CRUD solo se muestre 1 solo resultado de ese usuario, osea omitir resultados repetidos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Buen día, ¿`user_id` es la columna principal? ¿Deseas obtener los valores únicos de una o varias columnas? Creo que sería bueno que agregaras un ejemplo de los datos y el resultado esperado para entender mejor la pregunta

Comment: @HeytalePazguato si es de una sola columna, coloque una imagen para entender mas lo que necesito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Podrías utilizar [`unique()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-unique)

```
Reservas::where('user_id', $user)->where('dia_id', $dia)->unique('user_id')->get();
```

Ejemplo genérico:

```
$collection = collect([
    ['user_id' => 'Catalina', 'dia_id' => '21', 'algo_mas' => '5'],
    ['user_id' => 'Catalina', 'dia_id' => '21', 'algo_mas' => '5'],
    ['user_id' => 'Catalina', 'dia_id' => '21', 'algo_mas' => '5'],
]);
 
$grouped = $collection->unique('user_id');
 
dd($grouped->all());
```

Esto devuelve:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "user_id" => "Catalina"
    "dia_id" => "21"
    "algo_mas" => "5"
  ]
]
```